# Warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM when running First Aid of Disk Utility

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility

I run Catalina and when I run First Aid on Disk Utility App, it returns

```
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
```

and

```
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 125206461, refcnt 1)
```

Anyone can explain me, what is the meaning of those warnings?
My mac is randomly shutdown. Could it be possible because of those error?

Here are the complete First Aid Details :

```
Running First Aid on “Macintosh HD - Data” (disk1s1)

Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Verifying file system.
Volume could not be unmounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD - Data was formatted by hfs_convert (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 117115534, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 118309624, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 118703475, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 121125034, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 122691438, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 122990318, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 123417690, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 124020790, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 125203904, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 125206461, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 125975408, refcnt 1)
warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 126904909, refcnt 1)
Verifying allocated space.
Performing deferred repairs.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.

Operation successful.
```

Update : I can confirm that the random shutdown is not because of this issue. It because of logicboard issue.

Answer (score 2):

Same here. Macbook Pro Retina, 2015, on Catalina 10.15. Mac locks up randomly about once a day, and I can't do anything except reboot via power button.

Ran First Aid from Recovery Mode on "Macintosh HD - Data" and got this same sequence along with "Too many warnings of this type generated; suppressing subsequent ones."

I tried Apple Support Communities and didn't find anything exactly the same. Most were Mojave-related but [it sounds like a clean reinstall](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250248208) might be required.

Answer (score 1):

Same there. I am on macOS 10.15.4. My mac locks up randomly once a day as well. During lock up, I could still access in memory apps as well as Finder, but not Disk Utility, iStat Menu and etc that require some sorts of storage API. The only way to escape from that lockup is to do a hard-reboot by long pressing the power button. Then, I used cmd+r to enter the recover mode and run Disk Utility there. I got lots of above "unexpected dstream" errors which were not fixable through the First Aid.

Previously, I had my Time Machine automatic backup turned on. I saw those errors were on those local snapshots. Now I turned it off and deleted all my local snapshots. However, I could still see lots of those errors from regular file system in Disk Utility. I suspect this might have something to do with recent macOS changes, not sure whether directly related to Time Machine or not. Nevertheless, I have created a periodic backup schedule instead using [TimeMachineEditor](https://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/). I will report back when that lockup happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution sorry, but I have the same warning messages:

Running First Aid on “Macintosh HD — Data” (disk1s1)

Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Verifying file system.

Volume could not be unmounted.

Using live mode.

Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1

Checking the container superblock.

Checking the EFI jumpstart record.

Checking the space manager.

Checking the space manager free queue trees.

Checking the object map.

Checking volume.

Checking the APFS volume superblock.

The volume Macintosh HD — Data was formatted by hfs_convert (748.21.6) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1).

Checking the object map.

Checking the snapshot metadata tree.

Checking the snapshot metadata.

Checking the extent ref tree.

Checking the fsroot tree.

warning: xf : INO_EXT_TYPE_DSTREAM : found unexpected dstream associated with non-regular file

warning: found orphan dstream id object (id 34956820, refcnt 1)

Verifying allocated space.

Performing deferred repairs.

The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK.

File system check exit code is 0.

Restoring the original state found as mounted.

Operation successful.

So far my Mac seems to be working fine but I noticed these warning messages when doing a First Aid scan.

Comment: Exactly the same here today. My MBP is 2 YO and noticed something weird in one folder yesterday so I ran Disk Utility and ended up with the same message. I have not been able to find an explanation or a fix.

Answer (score 0):

it appears the fsck_apfs in Disk Utility by default runs in live mode, which can be only executed with -n (to deny any repairs).
To Fix, I need to unmount the volume with write access and run fsck_apfs -y to apply the suggested fixes.

This is what I did:

Rebooted to Recovery mode (Cmd+R)
Started Terminal
Run

```
diskutil umountDisk /dev/rdisk3
fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk0s2
```

That applied the fixes and the volume seems to be clean now